# Unable to configure Fiddler for localhost on Win 7 & IIS 7.5

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer-8, fiddler

I'm trying to debug ajax calls in my web app using Fiddler, but I'm unable to configure Fiddler to capture sessions on localhost. It captures every other "external" session like google or stack o, but not localhost.

I've tried the usual remedies: "localhost.", "machinename:8081/myApp.html", add oSession for localhost in rules file, "import windows hosts file" and so on. Nothing has worked. My environment is Win 7, IIS 7.5, IE8. Has anyone else faced the same issue, and how did you solve it?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ipv4.fiddler" as host name. See [here](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost)

Comment: tried that, get this error: Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) 

 
Your requested host "ipv4.fiddler" could not be resolved by DNS

Comment: In IE8 url, I enter http://ipv4.fiddler/district/index.cfm, hit enter. That's when the DNS error shows up. I wonder if there is something funky with my IIS 7.5 settings..

Comment: If Fiddler was properly installed as proxy, IE shouldn't even try to resolve that name. I guess that's where something goes wrong...

Comment: Bingo. If "ipv4.fiddler" doesn't work, Fiddler isn't hooked up properly. Note that "Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) Your requested host "ipv4.fiddler" could not be resolved by DNS" is not an IE error message, so you probably have some other proxy product running.